# Как сбросить кеш? Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как из init.php или из обработчика событий, сбросить Кеш шаблона компонента средствами Bitrix API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл решение) и этой функции почему-то я не нашёл в документации(
[image]

```
<?
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", Array("MyClass4", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateHandler"));

class MyClass4 {
    function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateHandler(&$arFields) {
        if ($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == 3) {
            CBitrixComponent::clearComponentCache('simplecomp:simplecomp.exam4');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Напишите текст программы в виде текста

Comment: Вам с комментариями?

Comment: Мне вообще все равно, я битриксом не пользуюсь :) Просто желательно чтобы был текст, по которому ваш ответ могут найти и он может оказаться полезен кому-то еще. А вам возможно плюсик в репутацию попадет ;)

Comment: И, кстати, замечание не по теме. Старайтесь не использовать теги `<?` (в пользу `<?php`) Это не касается `<?=` - лично я "за" такое использование.

Comment: это требования Битрикс

Comment: Эх. Плохо. Это противоречит хорошей практике в целом и PSR-1 в частности.

Answer (score 1):

Новое API

```
$staticHtmlCache = \Bitrix\Main\Data\StaticHtmlCache::getInstance();
$staticHtmlCache->deleteAll();
```

и описание некоторых подробностей [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=39&LESSON_ID=4875)

"Старое" API

Удаляет все (либо только устаревшие) файлы кеша по указанному пути.

```
BXClearCache()
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/other/bxclearcache.php)

Метод поддержки внутреннего кеширования компонента. Применяется, если при выполнении некоторых условий требуется очистить кеш компонента

```
ClearResultCache()
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cbitrixcomponent/clearresultcache.php)

Comment: Мне кажется, что это не подходит, так как эта функция сбрасывает весь html кеш, а мне нужно конкретного компонента, я пытался clearResultCache, но у меня там ошибки при изменении элемента инфоблока.